# New cookies for every session

Tags: ios, swift, session, cookies

If i ran multiple threads and do request in this threads:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)
var cookies = []

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
})
task.resume()
```

then i want to save cookies and set them to another request, like:

```
cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaderFields, forURL: response!.URL!)
```

but how to set this cookies to another request ? Or if i will use one session for requests, it will save cookies from requests automatically ?

Comment: Another session, another cookie ...

Comment: but if i have cookie from response  a=1 for example, when i do 

let task2 = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: {
    (data, response, error) in
})
task2.resume()

it will save ? or no ?